# Implementing MPI_Reduce with MPI_Send and MPI_Recv leads to wrong results

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I am working on a program that uses `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()` to replace `MPI_Reduce()`.

I get everything to run except the final bits of the code where it gives the PI approximate, error and runtime. I also don't get the correct sum value after receiving.

I believe there is something going wrong on the `MPI_Recv()` end but I could be wrong. I am only using 2 processors while running this. The program works fine without PI initialized to a value when using `MPI_Reduce`.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
 
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n, i;
    double PI25DT = 3.141592653589793238462643;
    double pi, h, sum, x;
 
    int size, rank;
    double startTime, endTime;
 
    /* Initialize MPI and get number of processes and my number or rank*/
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
 
    /* Processor zero sets the number of intervals and starts its clock*/
    if (rank==0)
    {
       n=600000000;
       startTime=MPI_Wtime();
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           if (i != rank) {
               MPI_Send(&n, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
           }
       }
    } 
    /* Broadcast number of intervals to all processes */
    else 
    {
        MPI_Recv(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }
 
    /* Calculate the width of intervals */
    h   = 1.0 / (double) n;
 
    /* Initialize sum */
    sum = 0.0;
    /* Step over each inteval I own */
    for (i = rank+1; i <= n; i += size)
    {
        /* Calculate midpoint of interval */
        x = h * ((double)i - 0.5);
        /* Add rectangle's area = height*width = f(x)*h */
        sum += (4.0/(1.0+x*x))*h;
    }
    /* Get sum total on processor zero */
    //MPI_Reduce(&sum,&pi,1,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&sum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&pi, 1, MPI_SUM, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    if (rank == 0) 
    {
        double total_sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        {
            MPI_Recv(&sum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            MPI_Recv(&pi, 1, MPI_SUM, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            total_sum += sum;
            printf("Total Sum is %lf\n", total_sum);
        }
    }
    
    /* Print approximate value of pi and runtime*/
    if (rank==0)
    {
       printf("pi is approximately %.16f, Error is %e\n",
                       pi, fabs(pi - PI25DT));
       endTime=MPI_Wtime();
       printf("runtime is=%.16f",endTime-startTime);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
MPI_Send(&pi, 1, MPI_SUM, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                 ^^^^^^^
```

and

```
 MPI_Recv(&pi, 1, MPI_SUM, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
                  ^^^^^^^
```

are wrong the [MPI_Send](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Send.html) and [MPI_Recv](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Recv.html) expect as third parameter `MPI_Datatype` not a `MPI_OP` (*i.e.*, `MPI_SUM`).

But looking at your code what you actually want to do is to replace those calls by:

```
double pi = sum;
if (myid != 0) {
        MPI_Send(&sum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
else {
    for (int i = 1; i < numprocs; i++) {
        MPI_Recv(&value, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        pi += value;
        }
}
```

To replace the behavior of the `MPI_Reduce`.

A running example:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
 
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n, i;
    double PI25DT = 3.141592653589793238462643;
    double h, sum, x;
 
    int numprocs, myid;
    double startTime, endTime;
 
    /* Initialize MPI and get number of processes and my number or rank*/
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid);
 
    /* Processor zero sets the number of intervals and starts its clock*/
    if (myid==0) {
       n=600000000;
       startTime=MPI_Wtime();
       for (int i = 0; i < numprocs; i++) {
           if (i != myid) {
               MPI_Send(&n, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
           }
       }
    } 
    else {
        MPI_Recv(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }
 
    /* Calculate the width of intervals */
    h   = 1.0 / (double) n;
 
    /* Initialize sum */
    sum = 0.0;
    /* Step over each inteval I own */
    for (i = myid+1; i <= n; i += numprocs) {
        /* Calculate midpoint of interval */
        x = h * ((double)i - 0.5);
        /* Add rectangle's area = height*width = f(x)*h */
        sum += (4.0/(1.0+x*x))*h;
    }
    /* Get sum total on processor zero */
    //MPI_Reduce(&sum,&pi,1,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    double value = 0;
    double pi = sum;
    if (myid != 0) {
            MPI_Send(&sum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 1; i < numprocs; i++) {
            MPI_Recv(&value, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            pi += value;
            }
    }
    
    /* Print approximate value of pi and runtime*/
    if (myid==0) {
       printf("pi is approximately %.16f, Error is %e\n",
                       pi, fabs(pi - PI25DT));
       endTime=MPI_Wtime();
       printf("runtime is=%.16f",endTime-startTime);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

**the output** (2 processes):

```
pi is approximately 3.1415926535898993, Error is 1.061373e-13
runtime is=1.3594319820404053
```